# C# LINQ How to Check if any element in a String array contains 'Error' or IsNullOrEmpty

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a statement that checks if any element in a string array contains `Error` text value.

```
bool containsError = myStringArray.Contains("Error", StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

How can I add another condition to also check if any element `isNullOrEmpty`?

Comment: `Contains` looks for items that match exactly. Use `.Any` to find if any item matches a condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add a condition with `Any()`:

```
bool containsErrorOrEmptyElement = myStringArray.Contains("Error", StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                                   || myStringArray.Any(s => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));
```

I used `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` after assuming it better fits your requirements; you can also use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` instead.

You can also use LINQ's `Any` for both conditions, by using the `string.Equals` method for case-insensitive comparison:

```
bool containsError = myStringArray.Any(s => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)
    || s.Equals("Error", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Note, that `s.Equals(...)` will be executed *first* and if `s` is `null` you'll have an *exception thrown*.

Comment: Great point @DmitryBychenko, I swapped the conditions so the `NullOr...` is executed first.

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like that :

```
var containsError = myStringArray.Any(e=> string.IsNullOrEmpty(e)  || 
                    e.Contains("Error", StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: The question's code looks for an exact match, so `e.Equals("Error",....)` is probably better

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos actually I was confused about this :`a statement that checks if any element in a string array contains Error` is looking for an element that contains the phrase or the array...

Answer (score 2):

If you want both information, so if a line contained "Error" or was null or empty:

```
List<(bool IsNullOrEmpty, bool IsError)> relevantStrings = myStringArray
    .Select(s => (IsNullOrEmpty: String.IsNullOrEmpty(s), IsError: s.Equals("Error", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
    .Where(x => x.IsNullOrEmpty || x.IsError)
    .ToList();

bool anyError = relevantStrings.Any(s => s.IsError);
bool anyNullOrEmpty = relevantStrings.Any(s => s.IsNullOrEmpty);
```